# How can i add data to the last element with specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an element via script like this:

```
 var fileExtra = '<input type="file" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-primary uploadFileExtra">';
 $("#extraUploads").append(fileExtra);
```

I want to add data to THE LAST inserted element.

I have tried the following:

```
 var lastInput = $("#extraUploads .uploadFileExtra:last-child");
 lastInput.data("files", file);

$(".uploadFileExtra:last").data("files", file)

$(document).find(".uploadFileExtra:last").data("files", file);
```

But no matter what way i try all elements with the specific class get the same value in the data-files attribute.

How do I do this correctly?

EDIT:

Scenario: 
using this script to set the data:

```
 $(document).find(".uploadFileExtra:last").data("files", file);
```

Using this script to see what data all elements contain: 
[image]

I uploaded 2 files, then uploaded two other files direclty after, but when i check the data of all input elements i see that they have the same data which is wrong.

Data 1
[image]

Data 2
[image]

EDIT 2:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc9zyoya/1/)

Press F12 and you will see that the console.log will write the same value for all

Comment: can u make a fiddle?

Comment: isn't the selector `:last-child` not `:last`? Oh nevermind, I did not spot the first line right

Comment: please provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: Well just a **[sample demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xc9zyoya/)** works fine for me..

Comment: made some edits, fiddle and pictures included. @Guruprasad Rao i extended your fiddle if you dont mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to all the help I got in the comments I approached this from a diffirent angle.

I added files into the data attributes of every input. 
Apperently this was going to fast so I tried putting this in a loop where i sent in a file at a time, like so:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                addInputs(file[i]);
            }

            function addInputs(file) {

                if ($(".uploadFile").data("files") != undefined) {
                    var fileExtra = '<input type="file" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-primary uploadFileExtra">';
                    $("#extraUploads").append(fileExtra);
                    var lastInput = $("#extraUploads .uploadFileExtra:last-child");
                    lastInput.data("files", file);
                }
}
```

It did the trick

Answer (score 3):

`:last-child` refer to the last child in a list of children in the direct parent. So for example if you have this :

```
<div id="extraUploads">
    <span><input type="file" class="uploadFileExtra" /></span>
    <span><input type="file" class="uploadFileExtra" /></span>
    <span><input type="file" class="uploadFileExtra" /></span>
</div>
```

Every `input` will be captured by the selector. Because each `input` is the last child of its direct parent (the `span`).

But, you can instead write this :

```
var lastInput = $("#extraUploads .uploadFileExtra").last();
```

You'll get the last `.uploadFileExtra` of the all `.uploadFileExtra` in the page.

Comment: no reason that `.last()` would work if selector `:last` doesn't work. but no reason either shouldn't be working properly either

Comment: Also, he is not wrapping each `input` into `span` right?

Comment: I can't see any other reason. We don't have all the code so maybe the wrapping is done elsewhere.

Comment: No spans, just the container div and the inputs

Comment: You'll have to provide a jsfiddle if you want more help.

Comment: I will setup a fiddle aswell, I just made some edits with pictures if you could perhaps take a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xc9zyoya/1/

press F12 and check the log output. All inputs will have the same data value

Comment: This jsfiddle works perfectly fine. See the console for yourself. You have 4 blank lines and only one line with `file`

Comment: I am adding files in the data atribute, might this be the problem why it is not working for me? Same files get added to all inputs with data-files